# How to generate a vector map of change from subtracting two rasters

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create an erosion map by subtracting two lidar based DEMs from one another and then turning that output into a vector that I can query elevation change from.

One of my first problems is I seem unable to clip the larger raster down to size of the smaller on. I have tried clip by masking where I created a vector from the smaller raster to use as a mask but for some reason the output looked identical to the original large raster.

I had previously subtracted the two rasters and was going to go ahead and vectorize the output, but the processing tool seems to just freeze on processing algorith with the progress bar solid blue before even reaching a % done estimate. I can't tell what is causing this as I have made a few vectors from rasters already.

Assuming I even can get a vector from the subtraction output, I'm not sure how I can get the vector to contain the difference in height as an attribute.

Sorry this is a rambling mess, I am rather new to using qgis and am at a complete loss as to how to solve these issues.

Comment: When you say you're "vectorizing" the raster, are you converting it into points or polygons? It may be too much data to convert to vector form, especially polygons. Try categorizing the raster, then use 'polygonize (raster to vector)' to convert the categories to polygons.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! I still have no experience in using lidar rasters. I understand that they are a grid or mesh of nodes in three dimensions. The procedure seems correct for handling "pixel" rasters. I think that if you could convert the format, move from _(  X, Y, Z )_ nodes to _( X, Y )_ pixels, giving the _Z_ coordinate to the pixel value, you would have no problem following the same procedure from there.